# Could not obtain release tasks status in VSTS Rollback task

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, powershell-3.0, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am using Rollback task with File Path to powershell script in VSTS Release pipeline. The script will read the task status and execute the rollback action.
But while executing it in Release pipeline getting below error.

> 2016-06-07T14:40:29.3618995Z ##[debug]Getting Personal Access Token for the Run
>
> 2016-06-07T14:40:42.1723249Z ##[debug]Calling https://aced.vsrm.visualstudio.com/HON.ACS.PIM.DAM.FWD/_apis/release/releases/158/environments/158/tasks?api-version=2.1-preview.1 using obtained PAT token
>
> 2016-06-07T14:40:42.6644892Z ##[debug]Could not obtain release tasks status
>
> 2016-06-07T14:40:42.6675181Z ##[debug]The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
>
> 2016-06-07T14:40:42.6714886Z ##[debug]Release Query unsuccessful.
>
> 2016-06-07T14:40:42.6905170Z ##[debug]obtained task execution history as {}

The script used is given below:

```
try
{
    $jsonobject = ConvertFrom-Json $env:Release_Tasks
}
catch
{
    Write-Verbose -Verbose "Error converting from json"
    Write-Verbose -Verbose $Error
}

foreach ($task in $jsonobject | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty)
{    
    $taskproperty = $jsonobject.$($task.Name) | ConvertFrom-Json
    Write-Verbose -Verbose "Task $($taskproperty.Name) with rank $($task.Name) has status $($taskproperty.Status)"
    Write-Verbose -Verbose "$($taskproperty.Name)"
    if($taskproperty.Name -eq "Execute Web deploy command" -and $taskproperty.Status -eq  "failure")
    {
        $statuscode = "$($taskproperty.Status)"
        Write-Host $statuscode
        #Setting up the environment variable for package install status
        Write-Output "Web Deploy Status Code is: $statuscode"
        Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=statusWebDeploy;]$statuscode")
        Write-Verbose -Verbose "statusWebDeploy:" $env:statusWebDeploy "Initiating Restore Website Folder..."
    }
}
```

Tried both inline script and File Path approach but did not work.
Please help.

Comment: What do you see when you use Fiddler to trace the call to: `https://aced.vsrm.visualstudio.com/HON.ACS.PIM.DAM.FWD/_apis/release/releases/158/environments/158/tasks?api-version=2.1-preview.1`, the fact that it returns an internal server error clearly indicates that your script is not at fault, The task is throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

There is a change in API version required in API which provides you a task status. Update your task script to latest version of API.
Please refer Question and Answer on VSTS Forum [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3ceed780-b02d-421f-8dbe-e22087bd80d9/debugcould-not-obtain-release-tasks-status-vsts-release-management-rollback-step?forum=TFService).